# Sagemaker Inference with Redis

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-sagemaker

I have a custom inference container on Sagemaker that runs a Flask API to handle the incoming calls. Around this, I have another API with a Lambda that calls the respective Sagemaker endpoint. The underlying model is generating vector embeddings for incoming sentences.

Now, I would like to enable caching and store already computed vectors with Redis.

My question: Does it make more sense to enable Redis on the inference container or in the Lambda API wrapped around the endpoint?

Comment: What do you plan to do with these vectors after you stored them in Redis?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the caching use case, there is also another option to cache on API gateway. If you do not need a full Redis feature, I think it is better (easier to maintain, cheaper too) to use API GW cache instead.